# Is it possible to open message queue in linux with huge number of elements?

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

According to [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max` can be used in order to increase the limit of messages in the queue. The documentation also says, that the limit should not exceed `HARD_MSGMAX`, which is `65,536` since Linux 3.5.

However, trying to open queue even with 500 elements fails with `EMFILE`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int message_size = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 16;
    int queue_size = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 10000;

    printf("Trying to open queue with msgsize: %d, and maxmsg: %d\n", message_size, queue_size);

    struct mq_attr initial_attributes = (struct mq_attr){
            .mq_msgsize = message_size,
            .mq_maxmsg = queue_size
    }; 

    int open_flags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
    int permissions = S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR;

    const char* name = "/message_queue_name;";
    mqd_t queue = mq_open(name, open_flags, permissions, &initial_attributes);

    if(queue == -1)
    {
        printf("Cannot open message queue\n");
        printf("Errno: %d [%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue has been opened successfully. Closing...\n");
        mq_close(queue);
        mq_unlink(name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tests:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max
65536

$ ./main 16 300
Trying to open queue with msgsize: 16, and maxmsg: 300
Queue has been opened successfully. Closing...

$ ./main 16 500
Trying to open queue with msgsize: 16, and maxmsg: 500
Cannot open message queue
Errno: 24 [Too many open files]
```

According to [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html), `EMFILE` error code means, that process already has the maximum number of files and message queues open, though this program does not open any other files.

So, my question is: how to open message queue with huge number of elements?

---

#### UPD [1]

This is my system limits:

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       62820
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 62820
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        30
-r: max rt priority                 99
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: Some other restriction? e.g. check `ulimit -a`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, hmm. `ulimit -q` (which is *"bytes in POSIX msg queues"*) is `819200`, so, I should be able to store about 50k 16-byte messages in a queue. I don't see any other limits - they are either `unlimited` or huge enough.

Comment: BTW, `return -1` from `main()` is an error.

Comment: @g-v, fixed, thank you again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have encountered [`RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) limit, see [`mq_overview(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html):

> **Resource limit**
>
> The `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` resource limit, which places a limit on the
>       amount of space that can be consumed by all of the message queues
>       belonging to a process's real user ID, is described in `getrlimit(2)`.

Increase it before calling `mq_open()`, e.g. like this:

```cpp
...
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct rlimit rlim;
    rlim.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
    rlim.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;

    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, &rlim) == -1) {
        perror("setrlimit");
        return 1;
    }

    ...
```

You need root privileges for that (or `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability, I guess).

---

Linux kernel really returns `EMFILE` for this case, check it [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/ipc/mqueue.c#L278):

```cpp
if (u->mq_bytes + mq_bytes < u->mq_bytes ||
    u->mq_bytes + mq_bytes > rlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE)) {
        spin_unlock(&mq_lock);
        /* mqueue_evict_inode() releases info->messages */
        ret = -EMFILE;
        goto out_inode;
}
```

The reason for `EMFILE` here is probably that it's the most close error code from those [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mq_open.html) in POSIX; `EMFILE` is the only error code that reflects reaching a *per-process* limitation.

POSIX doesn't specify a more precise error code for `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` because it is Linux-specific.

Comment: Awesome! Seems like this solves my problem entirely. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running out of file-descriptors. Just check the maximum number of file descriptors for each process (ulimit), if it's low then you can increase it to fulfill your needs by using

```
ulimit -n new_maximim_number
```

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. I have `1024` file descriptors per process, and even increasing it to `4096` does not solve the problem. I'll add the `ulimit -a` output to the question in a second. Thank you for the answer, though

Comment: Did you check when your program works how many file-descriptors actually it opens? ...  for example when you launch it with 300. This is just to check if each message queue opens 1 file descriptor or much more.

Comment: An other limitation may be the memory:

Comment: Just checked - each message queue opens exactly one file descriptor.

Comment: Do you mean, how much RAM is available? I have about 4GB free memory, so, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, because I just see in the ulimit: -q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200 ... so 500*819200  == 409600000 bytes

Comment: But the message size in my tests is `16`. Also, shouldn't `ulimit -q` show bytes per *queue*, rather than bytes per *message*?

Comment: As per the documentation this is the maximum number of bytes of a queue. I don't know if the memory reservation in this case will be performed before-hand or once you start using the queues. For that probably you can just check how much memory consumes your process when you launch it with 300 message queues

Comment: @redobot, FYI: `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is *not* another way to increase `RLIMIT_NOFILE`; it's a system-wide limit, while `ulimits` sets a per-process attribute.

Comment: @g-v yes, your are right, the second option is to increase the number at system level so it will impact all the processes not only the current running process.

Comment: Thanks. I removed this option part from the answer to do not confuse other users with similar questions.